# Workflow if-Else help

Tags: tasks

I have a workflow and the ending is not working for me no matter what I try. The point is that in **Collect 6** the person says YES or NO to a question. If they say NO, it goes to **Collet 7** and thats it. *( This works perfect)* BUT if they say yes it should go to **collect 8**, **then collect 9** skipping **collect 7**. BUT it is going to 7,8,9. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong for this second part. TIA!

http://postimg.org/image/ooeibgkn1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have messed up your if statements. See the image below and change your if blocks accordingly.

This image is not taken from the designer. I have edited your image to show the correct sequence.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have accidentally nested The if's. Move the second **if** down until it is outside of the first **if** and you should be fine.

Comment: Thank you! helped but still did not quite work.